# Internal Server Error when running unicorn with supervisor

Tags: flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I am encountering a problem when running my flask webapp on a VPS using unicorn and supervisor.
When running without supervisor everything works there are no internal server error not any problems with the app, everything works.

The problem arrises however when I want to user supervisor for monitoring. When running with it the main index loads, however when navigating to a page that requires a database connection an error happends.

It started happening when I decided to move my cloud based MongoDB to a local instance.

I don't know if supervisor is using a different route then the basic gunicorn, which in turn is getting blocked by my mongoDB.

If you have any ideas let me know.

Comment: Please show the error message (or stack trace, if that's what you're getting)

Comment: Its happening in production not in my dev enviroment. If u could tell me where flasks and gunicorn keeps the logs that be great

Comment: So i am getting the pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command find required authentication. I think therefore when i am using supervisor to run gunicorn

Comment: Without knowing your deployement environment, somewhere in `/var/log/` is the best I can do. It sounds like the app doesn't have the correct MongoDB credentials in production.

Comment: Thanks ! I figured it out by checking the gunicorn logs. Turned out I didn't have authSource in my URI for the connection.